# CORS : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

The CORS problem it shows:

OPTIONS https://dev-01-api-apptracker2/Admin 401 (Unauthorized)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-01-api-apptracker2/Admin' from origin 'https://dev-01-web-apptracker2' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But I think I already added a header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in my ajax code, and try many way to solve these CORS problem, I set dataType: 'json', crossDomain: true, and withCredentials: true, and also add different origin domain. But I still get error. 
I have no idea what's wrong with this, is anyone can help me. Thanks!!

```
AddAdmin: function (callback, UserId) {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, X-Custom-Header',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Method': 'POST',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            method: "POST",
            url: Services.APIBaseUrl + "Admin",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(UserId),
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    },
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("APIAllowedOriginsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://dev-01-web-apptracker2",
                        "http://localhost:31474")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("APIAllowedOriginsPolicy"));
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Add framework services.
            services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                });
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            //app.UseCors("APIAllowedOriginsPolicy");

            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
            );

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem that was because IIS Authentication problem, It need to allow both windows auth and anonymous for CORS.